# How to build Rubberband Library for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, build, libsndfile, rubber-band

I want to run rubberband cli in AWS Lambda, I tried the macos version of rubberband command-line utility using Layers but getting `"cannot execute binary file"`.

I need help on how do i build for AWS Lambda?

**Update**:

I build rubberband on Amazon Linux and ran on Lambda and got the following error:

```
rubberband: error while loading shared libraries: libsndfile.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

How to statically link libsndfile.so.1?

Ref: https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/